# What is the literal translation of this sentence: 一位球员连忙找来一把锯子把篮筐的底锯掉?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“何必这么麻烦呢？把篮筐的底去掉不就行了吗？”多亏了他这句话，人们如梦初醒，一位球员连忙找来一把锯子把篮筐的底锯掉。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 13.

Please help me understand the literal translation of this sentence: 一位球员连忙找来一把锯子把篮筐的底锯掉。

一(a)位(classifier)球员(player)连忙(promptly)找(find)来(?)一把(classifier)锯子(saw)把(the usual meaning of 把)篮筐(basket)的底(bottom)锯(to saw)掉(to fall)。

I have two specific questions:

What is the meaning of 来? Doesn't it look like something similar to 了 and 好? Particle used after verbs to denote the completion? Or just it means "to happen"? Usually it means to come, to arrive.

What is the meaning of 锯掉? Is it a verb with two characters or two verbs with one character each? to saw (and then) to fall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

来：indicates direction toward the speaker, opposite of 去，走 often not translated.

German has this 来：找来：**her**suchen:
Er suchte eine Säge irgendwoher.
He found a saw **from** somewhere.

把东西找来：seek something from (来) somewhere
掉：down, off, away, get rid of
锯掉: saw off
扔掉： throw away

何必这么麻烦呢？
Why so vexed?
把篮筐的底去掉不就行了吗？
Just get rid of the bottom of the basket and all is good, isn't it?
多亏了他这句话，
Thanks to his comment,
人们如梦初醒，
people were like they'd just woken from a dream,
一位球员连忙找来一把锯子把篮筐的底锯掉。
one player found a saw and cut away the bottom of the basket.

Answer (score 2):

In modern Chinese, there are many double-syllable verbs that are constructed with a simple verb and an adverb. Such as "找来" (find out) and "锯掉" (saw off).

Similar verbs may also include 找出，找到，锯开，锯断.

Other examples are:

做出 了 贡献 (made a contribution)

完成 了 任务 (completed the task)

学到 了 知识 (learned some knowledge)

踢进 一个 球 (scored a goal）

吃完 晚饭 (after supper)

飞过 高山 (fly over the mountain)

The two-syllable verb is a whole, not two verbs, not a verb followed by an adverb. The only case to separate the two syllables is the negative form with "不". For example:

找不到 一个 锯. (could not find a saw)

完不成 这个 任务. (can not get the job done)

吃不完 这么 多 米饭. (can not finish so much meal)